# Validate a link to check a user login are not

Tags: javascript, php

In a website by clicking a link, if the user login in that website ,the page redirects to another page otherwise it redirects to login page  how can we validate that page .can u give any solution for that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: i have no idea how to so pls can u help me

Answer (score 0):

you can done this with session. more detail about session : [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php%5fsessions.asp)

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {  
    header ("Location:dashboard.php");
  }
  else
  {
    header ("Location: login.php");
  }
?>
```

in this check if session is set then a user is login then redirect it to `dashboard.php` or if session is not set then it redirect to `login.php` page.

in login page set the session `$_SESSION['login']` with `1` or `0` value. or also you can store a username .

Answer (score 0):

In a website a user login is most of the time defined as a PHP-session. The answer for your question is to check if the session exists on the pages that need a login. If the session doesn't exist the user gets redirected to the login page

Example:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
   header('location: login.php');
}
else
{
   //Do nothing because the user is logged in.
}
```